# Boundary Case Testing in Java

Tags: java, testing, boundary

Are there any tools for JUnit or Java practises that allow for boundary case tests like "less than" and "greater than" to be accurately tested?

For example, rounding monetary values half-up to nearest cent.
Testing 0.005 rounds up to 0.01 is easy.
Testing <0.005 rounds down is not (strictly speaking).

I can obviously test an arbitrary value like 0.0049, but this doesn't guarantee that another value like 0.00499 doesn't get rounded up. Is there a constant or whatever that guarantees the numerical value that is the closest possible representation to "less than" or "greater than" for the environment being executed on?

Comment: *NOTE:* Using Hamcrest, there are actually convenience methods for boundary case testing, such as [greaterThan()](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#greaterThan%28T%29). I'd recommend using Hamcrest for assertions because it's more powerful than the JUnit assertions and they generate far more useful assertion failure messages without the need to write String messages manually. Hamcrest assertions/matchers also read far more like prose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably but this depends on many factors. For monetary values, you should always use `BigDecimal` since it gives you complete control over the precision (like `double` or `float` which can give odd results even for simple values)

Comment: Agreed that in this example BigDecimal should be used, but I haven't found a method in this class that will return an adjacent value, like the floating-point example above. Maybe due to the nature of BigDecimal this is not possible...

Comment: With `BigDecimal`, you can specify where the "corner" is. If you use two digits of precision, then that's what you get. There is no point to test for adjacent values since they will never appear. This code is always true: `value.setScale(2).compareTo(value) == 0`.

Comment: Good point, though of course "equals" wasn't the case that was the concern. Still, compareTo() == 1 or -1 will do the trick. I didn't see it until you pointed it out. I was expecting methods like .lessThan() .greaterThan()

Comment: `equals()` doesn't work with BigDecimal (well, it returns `false` for `0` == `0.00` while `compareTo()` returns 0)

Answer (score 3):

`Math.nextAfter (0.005, 0)`?

> Returns the floating-point number
>   adjacent to the first argument in the
>   direction of the second argument. If
>   both arguments compare as equal the
>   second argument is returned.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#nextAfter%28double,%20double%29

Comment: Testing won't help you if you commit a fundamental error like using floating-point for money.

Comment: While I generally agree that for monetary values, `float` and `double` should be avoided like the plague, this is very useful for the more general scenario, so +1.

Comment: Agreed that for this specific scenario this would not be a good choice, but this does actually do what I described I wanted in the general sense.